# is there any body know my button is not working for go on next page on android studio

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister1);
        c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
startActivity(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot a simple thing :-

```
c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
                startActivity(j);
            }
        });
```